# HTML divs not staying inside jumbotron

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having a problem where the divs (in this case `img`s) in my jumbotron are not being constricted to it. Ideally, the image would sit in the same horizontal position it is now, but the jumbotron would extend downward (or the image upward I suppose, but I want it to all be relative) in order to encompass the image. Is there a good way to do that? Any help is apprecitated!

```css
/* main color: #272950 */

body {
color: #fffae3;
background-color: #FF0000;    
}

.header {
    padding: 30px 0;
    background: #FF0000;
  }
  
.header .profile-image{
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    margin-right: 80px;
    
}

.header .profile-content .name {
    color: #49515a;
    font-size: 38px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    
  }

.header .container{
    background-color: #77dd77;

}

.jumbotron{
  background-color: #77dd77;
   padding: 5em inherit;
   background-size: auto 100%; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <img
            src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-6/128/profile-male-circle2-512.png"
            alt="me"
            class="profile-image img-fluid float-left"
          />
          <div class="profile-content float-left">
            <h1 class="name">AAAAAAAAA</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you dont have an appropriate question the code is working as expected!!

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `float-left` class.
I'd rather use flex in this instance.

```css
.profile-card {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron profile-card">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-6/128/profile-male-circle2-512.png" alt="me" class="profile-image img-fluid" />
  <div class="profile-content">
    <h1 class="name">AAAAAAAAA</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```